# C# - using "this" as a parameter to initialize a child class

Tags: c#, oop

I want to know that using "this" as a parameter to initialize a child class is a good idea or not? If I want to ask it better, I should ask that in OOP world it's a good idea to access a parent class variable from a child class or not?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you provide a sample code snippet to illustrate your meaning?

Comment: It's fine to access a parent class variable from a child class. How can the child class know what it's suppose to do otherwise? What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to pass a this pointer to the base class constructor, or to say that you want to initialize base class variables using the base keyword? Also, in C#, you use base, not this, when you want to initialize parent class variables, if that is what you mean. As others have already said, your question needs clarification.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing OP, if it makes sense to do so and it doesn't smell funny the go for it. If you want a more specific answer you're going to have to provide some code.

Comment: Are you talking about inheritance, for example you have a `class Vehicle{}` and a `class Car : Vehicle{}` that inherits from its parent *class*? Or are you talking about object hierarchy, for example a `class Tire {}` with a property `Vehicle Parent` in which you store the reference to the parent *object* that "holds" instances of child *objects*?

Comment: +1 for @Izzy, I totaly agree. It depends entirely on the context.

Comment: @Corak I think this is the crutch of the issue.

Comment: It seems that my comment didn't send correctly. any way Thanks for your helps. My question was something like what Knaģis said. It wasn't about inheritance. It was about instances. And as I found from answers it's a normal usage in OOP. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are planning on doing something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private OtherClass _someProperty;
    public OtherClass SomeProperty 
    {
        get
        { 
             if (this._someProperty == null) this._someProperty = new OtherClass(this);
             return this._someProperty;
        }
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    private MyClass _parent;
    public OtherClass(MyClass parent)
    {
        this._parent = parent;
    }
}
```

This is quite standard OOP approach. The one thing you should remember for more advanced scenarios is that now you have a cyclic reference between these two objects and Garbage Collector will not be able to collect either of them while one is still referenced.

Comment: Personally, i prefer to break the cyclic reference by extracting the required members from 'this' and declaring the constructor of the 'child' to only accept what it needs. If it actually needs a reference to its parent object then so be it (consider a linked list)

Comment: About Garbage Collector you're right. It was one of the things that I was worried about.

Comment: Depends what MyClass and OtherClass are doing ... But I would suggest if OtherClass is using properties / methods .. etc of MyClass then proper inheritance should be used instead. Kind of difficult to give a proper answer here.

Answer (score 1):

> in OOP world it's a good idea to access a parent class variable from a child
>   class or not?

This is not an idea, this is like `OOP` works actualy.

You declare *parent* class, derive from it *child* class and from *child* class you can access parent's `public`, `protected` and `internal` (if *child* and *parent* are in the same assembly) members.

This *is* OOP design for it's excelence.

If you're asking something else, please clarify.

Comment: OP is also talking about using `this` to initialise the child, so OP might not have used inheritance properly, or might be using a strange design pattern, but +1.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of a *child class*:

> A child class is a class that was derived from another, that will now be the parent class to it.

It sounds like your code looks something like this:

```
class Parent {}
class Child : Parent {
    Parent m_parent;
    Child(Parent parent){m_parent=parent;}
}
```

Storing a reference of the parent class is not necessary here; the child class already has access to its member variables. It can even use `base` when there is ambiguity.

Therefor, using `this` as a parameter to initialize a child class, to give it access to its parent class, is **not** a good idea.